# Python/SWIG: GC Object already tracked when trying to use a C function to dereference a pointer, from SWIG

Tags: python, c, exception, swig

I have an issue where I'm dealing with WORDs (2 byte unsigned integers). Here are the commands I usually run

```
import mySimLib
mySimLib.init()
strPtr = mySimLib.strInit( 200 )    #where 200 is the number of characters I want in the
                           #string. strInit returns a malloc'd pointer
wPtr = mySimLib.wordInit ()         # where wordInit returns a malloc'd pointer to a WORD.
mySimLib.Write ("Title", "Data", 4) # 4 is the number of bytes required to store data
mySimLib.Search ("Title", strPtr, 200, wPtr) #Search finds the record with same title,
      #copies the data into strPtr up to the number of bytes in the record - as long as
      #the number of bytes in the strPtr is greater. 

mySimLib.printWord (wPtr) #Since I cannot use python to dereference word pointers, I call a C function to print it out.
```

At this point, my program crashes. It throws an exception (reading violation) or some GC Object Already tracked error. The thing is - I have a string print function that never fails when I have it print. When I try to get the word to print, I do get errors.

This is my wordptr initiating function:

```
unsigned int * wordInit () {
    unsigned int * d = malloc ( sizeof ( unsigned int ) );
    *d = 0;
    return d;
}
```

This is my printing function:

```
void wordPrint (unsigned int * d){
    printf ("\nWptr: %d",*d);
}
```

I've no idea what I'm doing wrong here but these crashes are very erratic and annoying.

Comment: Well I can assure you that python isn't garbage collecting that memory. If you allocate it, it's up to you to deallocate it. One possibility (small) is that malloc is failing (you're not checking for that). What's happening in `mySimLib.Search`? That's the only other thing that uses your pointer...

Comment: All it does is dereference the pointer and assign it a value. :(

Comment: Is there any possibility that your library is stomping memory? Have you run it through a tool like valgrind?

Comment: I have not. Valgrind is for linux isn't it? Can you suggest any alternatives for Windows?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I know that IBM has a great product for memory profiling ("Purify" I think), but it's *incredibly* expensive. My only guess at this point is that at some point in your C module memory is becoming corrupted.

Comment: I just downloaded Purify but unfortunately, it wants to attach to visual studios. I'm using a python/swig interface to control the C module. I'm not sure if purify will work for this case. I do not get errors when I only run the C module...it's only when python is involved that things start to crash.

Comment: Hmm... without more code I'm hesitant to speculate any further. I'm afraid I don't know.

Comment: Would you know if there's a way to stop python from garbage collecting the wPtr pointer? I think it gets GC'd by python the moment the Search function is done with it.

Comment: That can't be the case because you use it again later. Python won't garbage collect a variable unless (a) you explicitly call `del`, or (b) the end of the `def` is reached. Furthermore, it has no way of garbage collecting manually allocated memory (unless you explicitly tell it how to). I highly doubt it's the garbage collector.